# nodejs - Invalid URI %22 - Quotes are matched to %22

Tags: node.js, uri

I am trying use the request module in node and i keep running into an issue about Invalid URI
code looks like below

```
       request.put(JSON.stringify(systemUrl),{

                json: {
                    description: "xxxx",
                    displayName: "xx",
                    id: JSON.stringify(name),
                    url: jsonUrl
                },
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": requestauth
                },
            strictSSL: false
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                //console.log("The error is " + error);
                console.log("The status code for system role unsuccessful is " + response.statusCode);
                console.log("The body for unsuccessful call is  " + body);
                callback(error,"setting system role unsuccessful");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Setting the role is successful \n");
                console.log("The response is \n" + response);
                console.log("The error  is " + error);
                //console.log("The body for unsuccessful call is  " + body);
                callback(null,"Setting system role is successful");
            }
        });
```

But i keep getting the exception
The error  is Error: Invalid URI "%22https://restofurl%22"

So , this is coming from systemUrl which is string i built like this ..
systemUrl = 'https://' + hostname + '/v1/id/name' + systemRole + '/' + defaultID;
where hostname and systemRole are variables.

The same request module works fine if i replace the variables with strings and have one contiguous string like "https://restofUrl".

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: why are u using JSON.stringify ?

Comment: When i used systemUrl as is , the backend throws me a 500 error .
So , i started experimenting with the complete string "https://xxxxxx" instead of the systemUrl variable. And that was successful.
So , i thought may be it needs a JSON string , and thats when i see this particular error about %22 invalid URI. Looks like the quotes are converted to %22.

Answer (score 0):

In your variable : 
`systemUrl = 'https://' + hostname + '/v1/id/name' + systemRole + '/' + defaultID;` , are you putting / after name ? , probably it should be : `'https://' + hostname + '/v1/id/name/' + systemRole + '/' + defaultID;` and avoid JSON.stringify.

Comment: Sorry , i missed that in the earlier post . I do have a "/" after the name https://' + hostname + '/v1/id/name/' + systemRole + '/' + defaultID. 
Thats what i have.